# How to use aggregate option with find option in go mongo drive

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to find a way to use aggregate option 'lookup' with find option in go mongo driver.
Documentation doesn't give any direct instruction to use aggregate with go mongo driver.

Is there any solution for use aggregate options directly with find options.

Comment: You can use the below function for that

    coll.aggregate(ctx context.Context, pipeline interface{},
     opts ...*options.AggregateOptions)

with $match and $lookup as two pipelines.

Answer (score -3):

> Is there any solution for use aggregate options directly with find options.

MongoDB [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) does not accept the same options as MongoDB [collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db-collection-find) options. Unfortunately there's no more context of which find() options you are after. If you're looking to specify find() [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) option, please see [$project aggregation pipeline stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project). You can add this stage after your [$lookup stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).

> Documentation doesn't give any direct instruction to use aggregate with go mongo driver.

The `Aggregate` method in [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) accepts a `pipeline` parameter, which should be a slice of documents, each representing a pipeline stage. `$lookup` would be one of these stages. For example, the pipeline
`[{$lookup: {from: "foo", localField:"x", foreignField:"y", as:"bar"}}]` would be written in the Go driver as:

```
coll.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{
    {{"$lookup", bson.D{
       {"from", "foo"}, 
       {"localField", "x"}, 
       {"foreignField", "y"},
       {"as", "bar"}
    }}},
})
```